# What Christian traditions reject Word of Faith teachings as heretical but still affirm the power of faith and its role in activating God's promises?

Tags: denomination-survey, faith, comparative-christianity, promises, word-of-faith

[Word of Faith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_of_Faith):

> Word of Faith is a movement within charismatic Christianity which teaches that those who believe in Jesus' death and resurrection **have the right to physical health**, **that our words have power**, and that **true faith is more than simply mental knowledge, it is deeply held belief that cannot be shaken**. The movement was founded by the American Kenneth Hagin in the 1960s, and has its roots in the teachings of E. W. Kenyon.

> **Teachings**
>
> Distinctive Word of Faith teachings include **physical, emotional, financial, relational, and spiritual healing** for those who keep their covenant with God. **The movement urges believers to speak what they desire, in agreement with the promises and provisions of the Bible, as an affirmation of God's plans and purposes. They believe this is what Jesus meant when he said in Mark 11:22–24 that believers shall have whatsoever they say and pray with faith**. The term word of faith itself is derived from Romans 10:8 which speaks of the word of faith that we preach.

Many dismiss *Word of Faith* teachings as heretical (for instance, as discussed in [*Is the Word of Faith movement biblical?*](https://www.gotquestions.org/Word-Faith.html)). Simultaneously, there is a belief among many that [Christianity is testable](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/97877/61679), implying that Christianity encompasses promises that can be tested through sincere and faithful engagement. I'm interested in the views of those situated at the intersection of both groups.

What Christian traditions consider Word of Faith teachings heretical but continue to uphold the belief in the empowering role of faith to activate God's promises?

---

**Notes**

1. By activating/testing God's promises, I'm specifically referring to the belief in promises that can be tested *on this side of the grave*. Therefore, promises that only become actualized *on the other side of the grave*, such as resurrection to eternal life, for the purposes of this question, do not count.
2. My use of the word *activate* has been criticized as inappropriate in the comments section. My observation in response is that my use of this word in the context of God's promises is not novel. With a quick search one can easily find several examples of churches/ministries that have used it in this way. For instance:

   - [GOD’S PROMISES AREN’T AUTOMATED, THEY’RE ACTIVATED](https://www.redeemercoast.church/blog/2021/1/22/gods-promises-arent-automated-theyre-activated)
   - [3 Keys to Activating God’s Promises in Your Life](https://faithisland.org/bible/3-keys-to-activating-gods-promises-in-your-life/)
   - [Activating the Promises of God: Unlock the Power of the Bible & Empower Your Life](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0CR31XPYS)
   - *"Perhaps they did not believe that such a simple action could **trigger the promised healing**. Or perhaps they willfully hardened their hearts and rejected the counsel of God’s prophet."*

     *"The principle of **activating** blessings that flow from God is eternal.* [...] *In fact, it can be seen in heaven because small acts of faith are required to **ignite God’s promises**."*

     *"I invite you to faithfully **activate heavenly power to receive specific blessings from God**. Exercise the faith to strike the match and light the fire. Supply the needed oxygen while you patiently wait on the Lord. With these invitations, I pray that the Holy Ghost will guide and direct you so that you, like the faithful person described in Proverbs, will “abound with blessings.” I testify that your Heavenly Father and His Beloved Son, Jesus Christ, live, are concerned with your welfare, and delight to bless you, in the name of Jesus Christ, amen."* (source: [Abound with Blessings](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/general-conference/2019/04/41renlund?lang=eng))

   What I'm having a hard time verifying is whether any of these ministries denounce *Word of Faith* teachings as heretical, or if they are tacitly endorsing them.

Comment: What churches *don't* affirm the power of faith and God's promises?!? That's not a useful thing to ask about.

Comment: @curiousdannii I understand that some cessationist denominations would be reluctant to pray for miraculous healings or expect miracles in general, so promises such as Mark 16:17-18 would be rejected.

Comment: @Mark Cessationist is not only one type, it's more of a spectrum.  Gavin Ortlund recently refutes the ultra-cessationist John McArthur [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V0EXiv5TFDo).  I myself has this common-sense stance: God can do miracles if He wants.  Just ask and it *may* be given.  If medical doctors or scientific examination cannot provide an explanation, then it's a miracle.  Doesn't matter what our cessationist vs. continuationist stance is.  The cessationist issue is more critical in regards to Prophecy and Apostolic office; both has to do with authority rather than miracles.

Comment: @Mark about Mark 16:17-18, mainstream don't interpret the "will accompany" as promise to an *individual*, but to the *whole church* (Mark 16:15 "Jesus said to **them**" in the context of world evangelization).  That is why there's what called [concentric cessationism](https://atwistedcrownofthorns.com/2017/09/21/the-four-groups-of-cessationists/) which notes how in the fringes there are more miracles to facilitate conversions.  But WoF is VERY individualistic, I think there is some American  Dream mixed in, making WoF a syncretism.

Comment: @Mark No, I'm quite confident that no cessationists would reject the promise of Mark 16:17-18 (ignoring the text critical issues...) Just because they interpret it differently doesn't mean they reject God's promises!

Comment: @curiousdannii How is Mark 16:17-18 then interpreted?

Comment: @Mark Personally I would have worded your question differently. Something like what Wof teachings are in conflict with orthodox/right belief Christianity? For instance Kenneth Copeland stated in one of his tapes, "You don't know what happened at the cross." He then goes on to explain how Jesus died spiritually and took on Satan's nature, was born again in hell and was tortured by Satan. Finally God the Father bellowed, "Let Him be. Plus these wof teachers have made numerous false prophecies. Also, Jesus told Copeland that He did not claim to be God. Just giving my opinion for what's its worth

Comment: @Mark That's a question for the [hermeneutics.se] site.

Comment: God's promises are not 'activated' by humanity. God _keeps_ his promises and _fulfils_ them when appropriate. God made his promises and he is faithful to keep them. The question starts on earth among humanity instead of beginning with God himself. The question lacks proper focus.

Comment: @NigelJ I edited the question with a note about the word 'activate'. Feel free to let me know what you think.

Comment: None of the links, nor the organisations propagating the wordage of those links, has any constructive defence to make in regard to my comment. I stand by my comment. No such wording (and no such concept) appears anywhere in scripture. It is modern and novel and without support from the word of God.

Comment: In response to Nigel, Mr. Bond and curiousdannii's comments to make the question more useful, how about rephrasing it as How do various Christian traditions respond to Word of Faith's understanding of "the power of faith" and of "activating God's promises"?  It then does NOT imply that non WoF tradition does NOT believe in God's fulfilling his promises, etc.  That way you still have answers responding to WoF's meaning of "activating promise" verbiage although not used in the mainstream as @NigelJ said.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple I would need to provide evidence to justify the attribution of those specific phrases to the WoF movement. If you can help me with that, I'd be happy to edit the question. Or feel free to suggest the edit directly using the built-in functionality of the site.

Comment: @Mark We'll see whether explicit attribution is needed, but I think the term "activation" is telling already (as you'll see in my upcoming update). You'll find that  tying the theology of a blog, book, or even church to WoF/PF is often hard, since they tend to be media savvy and they *know* the negative connotation attached to WoF/PG (BTW, those are *outsider* labels). When they're more upfront they use an *insider* label "Full Gospel", implying they have something more to offer (i.e. healing, flourishing, power, gifts) than a typical mainstream church, which becomes their selling point.

Answer (score 3):

**Answer**: ALL Christian traditions, including non-Trinitarians movements such as Jehovah's Witnesses & Latter-day Saints!  The key difficulty of your question is the ambiguity of meaning "power of faith" and the nature of *how* and *when* God fulfills his promises.  An academic study (from UK, published this century, cannot recall, will update this answer when I find it) concluded that the core issue is [**over-realized eschatology**](https://nickcady.org/2017/06/28/what-is-over-realized-eschatology/) in how that heresy interprets God's promises.

Yes, ALL traditions teach that God promised there **WILL** be no sickness, and abundant wealth. The question is WHEN; prior to WoF, the answer is:

- **for sure**, in the new heaven and earth, but
- **for now**, we can ask and God willing He will grant us a few fortuitous healings (or even miraculous healing), a few deliverances from  misfortunes or from devil's possessions, and a blessing for our material prosperity.

To obtain them, "faith" is *NOT* the *instrument* (i.e. increasing faith has *NO* cause-effect relationship to the amount of blessing as though if you have more faith you'll get a Lamborghini instead of a Mercedes) but the *purpose*.  I mean, when God *does* give us those goods in response to prayer, we should interpret those blessings as God's way to prod us along to trust God more (i.e. trusting His wisdom as to the timing, the amount, and the manner) so that we are willing to take more risk for Jesus!

The proper understanding of "power of faith" is continued trust in God in the midst of suffering, with Job as the paradigmatic example, thus **power over hopelessness / meaninglessness**.  This is what ALL Christian traditions teach.  Other meaning of "power" would be *not* power to be someone (like the power of positive thinking) or to get whatever you desire, but **power over disorder** introduced by Satan, such as power over sin (individual level) or power over injustice / callousness toward the weak (society level) introduced by Satan.

Yes, that means those traditions interpret Jesus's words to mean something that on face value seem to teach [prosperity gospel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosperity_theology), but then interpretation needs to take into account the whole canon, not just the meaning of a phrase taken out of context.

P.S. To improve this answer, I would have to provide references for major traditions that say WoF is heretical; but I think it's obvious enough.  Maybe some day if there is a serious need for it.

Comment: Good answer, but a possible counterexample: not all Christian traditions necessarily endorse all promises you find in the Bible. One example is Mark 16:17-18. Denominations that adhere to a cessationist theology would very likely say that such a promise no longer holds.

Comment: I made a slight edit to the question. Feel free to adjust your answer accordingly or disregard this comment.

Comment: You might probably want to say something about the word 'activate', that Nigel finds inappropriate in the comments section. I also edited my question once again in response to that.

Comment: @Mark Yes, your edits make your question better because of additional reference (so I just +1 it).  I'm busy at the moment, but will respond it either tonight or tomorrow.  I already have a few contrasts to be made between those who use the language of "activation" vs. the right kind of growth of faith that I spoke about in my recent answer, since I know first hand (because of my good friend who is a victim to prosperity gospel) the subtle deceptiveness that can insinuate itself into the correct practice of Christianity.  He also quoted Mark 16:17-18 about the "promise".

Comment: @Mark about Nigel's comment, I basically agree with him theologically, but I tend to be more generous about using terms in our native English language (as opposed to English conformant to Hebrew/Greek idioms used in the Bible). Instead, I approach terms as *indicators* (like "code words", or "insider language") to identify a sociological group (i.e. prosperity gospel) among the billions of Christian based on *how they talk*.  It's quite distressing that their influence is growing, esp. among the Global south where new conversions happen. "activate" is one such code word and I'll respond to it.

Comment: I expanded my question with an additional example from the Latter-day Saint church. Any thoughts on that one?

Comment: @Mark I only know LDS theology and their central concerns a little.  Haven't considered their link to WoF / PG but that LDS quote makes me think of a link though I'm sure they assign a different meaning to "activating".  It's a good edit to the Q, one that my answer needs to respond to.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Go to this LDS frequrntly asked questions link which shows that LDS believe only they have restored true worship since the death of the apostles and the visions given to Joseph Smith: https://newsroom.churchofjesuschrist.org/article/frequently-asked-questions

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Regarding Jehovah's Witnesses they also claim to be the only true church and say this: "With regard to any denomination that believes in the trinity or does not use the name Jehovah, they are considered to be part of the Antichrist.  That would include most Protestant denominations and Catholicism."  Source: June 2015 Watchtower magazine https://www.jw.org/en/library/magazines/wp20150601/who-is-the-antichrist/

Comment: @GratefulDisciple - Both LDS and JW's claim they alone have the true church and are Jehovah's chanel of communication today.  I think that means they would both reject the Word of Faith movement whilst still believing in faith as being essential.  As for "activating God's promises" I do not know what that means (nor do I care). Salvation is the work of God from start to finish.